# AG-Grid - How to get the parent headerName

Tags: ag-grid

I have a merged header in ag-grid. Im trying to update the parent header name 'Details'.
The following is the simplified column definition.

I am able to get and update the headerName of the children header by using

```
$scope.ag_gridOptions_data.columnApi.getColumn("Items")
```

However my parent header do not have a field so I cannot use the above code.
I tried to give it a dummy field but it returns null.

```
var my_colDef= [
    {
        headerName: 'Details',
        children:[
            {
                headerName: 'Id',
                field: 'Items'
            }
        ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The column name can be dynamic. You just need to configure `colDef.headerValueGetter` to return the new header name and then call `api.refreshHeader()` to refresh the header.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/osfJhb4G6Yz1NoC2GjMG?p=preview)